# How to find the last modified Bucket in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to store the information about, which s3 Bucket was last modified. Studying the documentation makes me wonder if s3cmd 'sync' would be of use. I'm new to Amazon s3, so please help me by suggesting the best way to get the information about the last modified Bucket and also store it in a log using s3cmd. Anyone to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bucket in S3 cannot be modified. If you means last modified time of object in bucket, you may make use of s3cmd sync with `--dry-run` option, and print the output to an log file.